# iFrame src not working with Base64 Encoded HTML Content in Android Webview

Tags: android, reactjs, iframe, webview

I'm developing a project for an app that will display my react app in a webview.
ReactJS app works perfectly in webview, that is why I assume JS is activated in webview.
But, I'm trying to display a base64 encoded HTML content which I'm trying to display as follows;

`` <iframe src={`data:text/html;base64,${HtmlContent}`}/> ``

This approach works fine in the browser (Chrome), but it's not working at all in the webview.

I used `srcdoc` instead of `src`. But then I cannot `postMessage` to parent ReactJS app.

Is there a way to work with `srcdoc` in this scenario or what could be the problem with the iframe when in webview?

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: Nope. Instead, I create a function in window object like window.getMessage (etc), than I can use that function within the iframe. In iFrame you can call it like, window.top.getMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfutenally I couldn't manage to work with this approach.
But, since I can control both and of the iframe, simply I created a function in the parent of the iFrame as follows;

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Only create once
    // Create a custom function and put it to the window object
    window.handleResult = handler;
}, [])
```

Then access it from inside of the iFrame with;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.top.handleResult({success: params.success, error: params.error})
</script>
```

This approach worked better actually. If you need one more nested iframe for some reason, you can get this function no matter how deep it is because, iframe content geting "**top**" window anyway.

I'm sharing this because this problem can be solve with different aproches. Maybe not the best way but it'i **a** working way.